# Failed to detect set buildpack in Python

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I'm new to python Flask and I'm trying to push my app to Heroku. I've already included requirements.txt file as well as the Procfile in the root directory. But I keep getting this message:

```
remote: -----> Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazon   aws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-fa   ilure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to fathomless-taiga-95236.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/fathomless-taiga-95236.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/fathomless-taiga-9523            
6.git'
```

Comment: Did you go to the help page in the error message? How is the build pack configured?

Comment: Found the issue. I committed everything but didn't really add the requirements.txt file